# Even after entering password in command line , still prompting for password

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a password protected sheet to another workbook where in i have to merge multiple sheets, the workbook that i am trying to copy is password protected ,

so i entered the password as well in syntax of opening the file but still it is prompting the same , i tried Rewritepassword syntax as well but still again it is prompting

```
Sub GetSheets()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/2/20
    Path = "D:\My Path\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
     If (Filename = "scenarios.xlsx") Then
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, Password:="*****", 
                  WriteResPassword:="****", ReadOnly:=True
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
        Sheets("Data").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
     End If
     Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub


The password to unlock workbook is same as the other passwords that are popping up
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `Password` parameter in `Workbooks.Open` is just the password you need to open/view the file, it has nothing to do with the protection of the workbook/worksheet. If the workbook/worksheet is protected then you probably still need to use the …

- [Workbook.Unprotect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.unprotect) to unprotect the workbook
- [Worksheet.Unprotect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect) to unprotect the worksheet

Also note that if you can open your file for viewing without entering a password, then you must not specify the `Password` parameter in `Workbooks.Open` (or it will keep asking for the correct password which is actually none).

Further improvements:

1. I recommend to stay away from `ActiveSheet`
2. Use `Option Explicit` to force proper variable declaration and set your opened worksheet to a variable so you can use it later for further actions relying on this workbook.
3. If you turn off `.DisplayAlerts = False` then you should reactivate it later or it will stay off until Excel is closed.
4. You don't need to loop to check if the file `scenarios.xlsx` exists

So I think it should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const PASSWD As String = "yourpasswordhere" 'define your password only once

Public Sub GetSheets()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/2/20
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "D:\My Path\"

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Dir(Path & "scenarios.xlsx") 'check if file exists

    If Filename <> vbNullString
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'comment out this line for Debugging (or you don't see if something goes wrong

        Dim wbScenarios As Workbook
        Set wbScenarios = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

        'unprotect workbook and/or worksheet (test which one you need or if you need both)
        wbScenarios.Unprotect Password:=PASSWD 'defined on top of the module
        wbScenarios.Worksheets("Data").Unprotect Password:=PASSWD 'defined on top of the module

        wbScenarios.Worksheets("Data").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        wbScenarios.Close SaveChanges:=False

        'if you insert after sheet 1 then your inserted sheet is Sheets(2)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).AutoFilterMode Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    End If
```